# Why is `this` losing its bind to my object?

Tags: javascript, recursion, this, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a recursive method but it is losing its binding to `this`. Here is the simplest way to recreate my issue:

```
var Foo = function() {
    return {
        foo : 'foo',
        bar : function() {
            co​nsole.log(this.foo);
            setTimeout(this.bar, 500);
        }
    }​;
}
var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();​
```

That will only run twice. The first time it will log `foo` to the console, and the second it will log `undefined`. Then of course, it won't run anymore because `bar` is no longer a property of `this` since I assume it was reset to the global object.

I tried `var that = this` in my `bar` method and referencing `that.foo` and `that.bar` but it doesn't change anything. I also tried `var that = this` above my `return` statement and the issue persists.

Expected result:

> foo
>
> foo
>
> foo
>
> foo
>
> ... and so on

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/k2hTJ/ which results in this:

> foo
>
> undefined

Comment: Because `this` is overriden in the scope of the function.

Comment: We should come up with a name for the `that = this`, `self = this` conundrum that seems to haunt javascript developers on a daily basis.

Comment: From the way your code looks, I deduce that you're well on your way to learning about the module pattern. Fantastic, but if you don't mind my being pedantic: in this case, a prototype method might be more suitable, because now you're creating a new function object for each new instance... all `bar` properties are separate objects that do exactly the same thing. That's not ideal. If you don't want to augment the proptotype, a closure will do just as well of course

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the above code using the module pattern for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` will call its function in the current scope, but with `this` as the global object.

The best way to work around this is to do something like:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function() {that.bar.apply(that);},500);
```

Comment: @Alexander inside the anonymous function `this` scope has changed

Comment: AH Thank you! I read about call and apply the other day and must have been too overwhelmed to remember it.

Comment: @Ibu, Elias Van Ootegem, you better read again. There's no logic in the anonymous function

Comment: @ibu: That doesn't matter: `that.bar()` calls the function object, referenced by `bar` in the context of `that`, whatever `this` references in the anonymous function is irrelevant. If it did matter, then `someObject.bar()` in the global scope would meant that `this` would point to the global object here, too (which it doesn't)

Comment: @Alexander: Sure there is... the apply is not required IMO, but it's not harmful either. I was wrong about omitting the parentheses (thinking about Nick's answer there)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var Foo = function() {
    return {
        foo : 'foo',
        bar : function() {
            co​nsole.log(this.foo);
            setTimeout(this.bar(), 500); //Add '()'
        }
    }​;
}
var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();​
```

Comment: It might well work, but it doesn't do the same thing: this calls the return value of the method after half a second, not the method itself

Comment: Congratulations. You just created an infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: function() {
        console.log(foo.foo);
        setTimeout(foo.bar, 500);
    }
};
foo.bar();​
```

This will also do the trick.